# How can I run mutiple canvas in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I have two canvas, now I want to have firework in two canvas. But it's not work, it only run in left canvas or right canvas.

`This is code` [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/greenlove/p6zsLo1p/)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) All your variables are global. That's why you cannot use multiple objects.

2) Some issue with this:

```
SCREEN_WIDTH = $('.fireworks').innerWidth(),
SCREEN_HEIGHT   = $('.fireworks').innerHeight(),
```

it gets width/height only from first element. It should be rewritten to use `obj`'s parent.

```
SCREEN_WIDTH = $(canvas).parent().innerWidth();
SCREEN_HEIGHT = $(canvas).parent().innerHeight();
```

Here is the updated fiddle (I just added `var` to all your variables and moved initialization of width/heigth to `init` function):

https://jsfiddle.net/p6zsLo1p/3/